# Manually plotting confidence intervals of interaction from generalized linear mixed model

Tags: r, python, lme4-nlme

I have a glmer model in R that does something similar to `correct_response ~ time*kappa_score + (1|pid)`. Because I generally prefer plotting in python, I save model coefficients and emtrends data to disc and want to plot the interaction of time & kappa at two time points as a function of kappa.

To do this, I am currently running:

```py
CI = 1.96
kappa = np.linspace(-1, 1, 1000)
time = np.linspace(-2.5, 2.5, 1000)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows = 1, ncols = 3, figsize = (6.6, 2.0))

# kappa interaction early
lower = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-((ß_kappa - CI*SE_kappa)*kappa + (ß_tkappa - CI*SE_tkappa)*time.min()*kappa)))
upper = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-((ß_kappa + CI*SE_kappa)*kappa + (ß_tkappa + CI*SE_tkappa)*time.min()*kappa)))
mu = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-((ß_kappa)*kappa + (ß_tkappa)*time.min()*kappa)))
ax[0].fill_between(kappa, lower, upper, alpha = .25, color = colors[0])
ax[0].plot(kappa, mu, '--', alpha = 0.9, color = colors[0], linewidth = 1)

# kappa interaction late
lower = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-((ß_kappa - CI*SE_kappa)*kappa + (ß_tkappa - CI*SE_tkappa)*time.max()*kappa)))
upper = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-((ß_kappa + CI*SE_kappa)*kappa + (ß_tkappa + CI*SE_tkappa)*time.max()*kappa)))
mu = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-((ß_kappa)*kappa + (ß_tkappa)*time.max()*kappa)))
ax[0].fill_between(kappa, lower, upper, alpha = .25, color = colors[3])
ax[0].plot(kappa, mu, '-', alpha = 0.9, color = colors[3], linewidth = 1)
```

However, the results that I obtain are confusing to me (see attached image). While the confidence interval for time = 2.5 seems reasonable to me, the one for time = -2.5 absolutely does not (given that it is barely noticeable). I have checked in R using `plot(effects("time*kappa_score"), x.var = "kappa_score")`, which produces plots that seem comparable, except that there the confidence interval for time = -2.5 is substantially larger.

[image: My attempt at plotting the CIs]

Now, I realise that this is due to `time.min()` being negative, but I can't help but wonder how these are calculated differently in R (see attached image). Does anybody have any insights?

[image: Results from R]